# Does Tumah Wear Off or Expire from an Object?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah

Does tumah contracted from a niddah wear off or expire? Like a seat that she sat on? According to the times when the Temple stood?
*edited

Comment: Are these two separate questions. 1- the actual person 2- Things a Niddah make tumah? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, Tumah does not wear-off an object - no matter how much time has passed.

If an object is badly decayed or been melted down or transformed into another object, then it sometimes loses its Tumah status.

---

BTW:

In some Rabbinically decreed Tumah, like certain bloods and spittle, once it's dry it loses its Tumah status. This was decreed purposely to be able to differentiate between Rabbinic and Torah-ordained Tumah.

Regarding the Nidah herself, her Tumah status remains forever until she goes to Mikvah after keeping 7 clean days.